# Picking a suitable class name for a randomiser

Tags: java, class, oop, inheritance

I apologise firstly and foremost if I have put this in the wrong place. But I believe this to be an inherent programming design decision, hence why it is here.

I am working on an android game which has various classes that are related via inheritance.

I have a Coin object, and a Die object (as in a single Dice), the Die object has another subclass, CustomDie (which allows a user to define a die with many faces, i.e. 7 sided dice).

Since both the coin and die have very similar functions, the coin picks a random number between 1 and 2, and the die does that between 1 and 6 and the custom die does this between (n,m) or whatever range the user has defined. I was thinking about putting some of the functionality in a parent class.

I am not sure what the class would be called, perhaps something along the lines of RandomGenerator or RandomPicker. Any suggests would be welcome.

I agree that most of the answers will be based on opinions, but there is a degree of knowledge required, i.e. use of verbs/nouns; to pick a good class name. This will later affect the choice of method names and other classes/variables used in the project. And good software architects will converge on one or two of the best suggestions, so please dont write the question off as one that cannot be answered.

Comment: Answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. You can choose any name you find suitable.

Comment: I prefer RandomPicker, since you already mentioned the word 'pick'

Comment: @jlordo I agree that most of the answers will be based on opinions, but there is a degree of knowledge required, i.e. use of verbs/nouns; to pick a good class name. This will later affect the choice of method names and other classes/variables used in the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you are someone who has never seen your code before, and they have to understand it and fix a bug.  What is the clearest possible name you can give it, which will express what it does and suggest that it is the parent class of Coin and Die?

I'd suggest avoiding verb-like names in this case, since you do something to a die or coin to produce a number - a coin doesn't proactively generate numbers;  you must do something to it to get a number.  So anything ending in -er, to me at least, doesn't suggest "parent class of a coin or die".

Tossable? RandomValued?

Comment: +1 for "avoid verb names". Classes effectively are nouns not verbs (see [Kingdom of Nouns](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com.es/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Your class design is not valid.

In sense of behavior a coin and dice are equal, but something that throw them is not. There fore you can not apply inheritance here. The classes should represent the abstract of our world. You should try to decompose the object by its properties not appearance. Coin and Dice for sure look different but act in the same way.

If you will get closer look. I will provide to point when you establish that something common called Die, is a construction that is build upon Faces that bring to you information. But it is up to you how you get this result, one of then method is throwing the die. The throwing process is logically equal to selecting random face of die. So at the end you can call the procedure that will get result in two ways. `getRandomFace` or `throwFace`. ThrowFace is more intuitive for human but for coder could be misleading especially in Java where throw is a key word.

The first class you need is class to represent face of dice.

```
public final class Face {

   private  String displayName;

   Face(String displayName) {
       this.displayName = displayName;
   }

   public String getDisplayName() {
      return this.displayName;
   }

}
```

As dice is nothing more that list of Faces

```
public final class Die {

  private Face[] faces;

  public Die(Face[] faces) {
    if(faces == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Faces must not be null"); 
    if(faces.length < 2) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Die must have at least two faces");
    this.faces = faces;
  }

  public Face getFace(int face) {
     return this.faces[face];
  }

  public int getFaceCount() {
     return this.faces.length;
  }
}
```

On the end we need something that will throw the Dice to get the face. We can create a utill class with static method to support different action over Dice.

```
public final class DieUtill {

   public static final Die COIN   = new Die(new Face[] {new Face("head"),new Face("tail")});
   public static final Die DICE   = new Die(new Face[] {new Face("1"),new Face("2"),new Face("3"),new Face("4"),new Face("5"),new Face("5")});

   public static final Face getRandomFace(Die die) {

     int face = new Random().nextInt(die.getFaceCount());

     return die.getFace(face);

   }

}
```

If we require more complex logic about the random value you should create a class like FaceRandomizer and then pass in constructor a Dice and implement the random logic.

Comment: Either I did not understand what you said or you contradicted yourself. You say "There fore you can not apply inheritance here". In your DieUtill class you have a Coin and Dice, and both are of type Die. They both have an array of Faces passed to them in the constructor. This is bad design - a coin will ALWAYS have 2 sides, so should this be passed on as an array during construction? A dice will ALWAYS have 6 faces, should this be passed on during construction? Why not have a superclass with getface() and child classes with static final enums or arrays of faces?

Comment: @Husman, You can not apply inheritance between (Coin or Dice) and Thrower, as thrower has nothing common with Coin or Dice. It something that operate on them, but it is not them.

Comment: @Husman, The Coin and Dice are only form of representation of Die. Having a class that is a Coin you should be also able to Pay but this functionality is not valid for Dice. There fore if you convert a class Die into interface. Then you will be able to use coin to pay and throw it. With your logic when you inherit Dice from Coin you will be able also pay with Dice, and this is a bad design.

Comment: @Husman, As to the point that coin has always two faces, there is no point of having a class. Objects are for that type or restriction as the class is only an description. Object is representation. and in the DieUtill class you have  two static fields COIN and DICE that fits your limits.

Comment: @Husman, to conclude. During class design you should avoid to give them characters from real life. A Coin is only state of die in this case. For sure you can disagree on this point. But when you will be creating same logic for car then you will heave a class that represent by name each brand model etc. So when you are passing argument to constructor you define what this die will be (object). On the level of definition (class), is everything. And this is a good design.

Comment: There is no need to pay for anything; the coin does not represent currency here. I don't think there is any reason to model ALL aspects of an objects real life properties in a class otherwise would end up with far too many bugs and complexity. Its good enough to abstract just enough functionality into the class to get the system working. In this case, we need a coin with 2 faces and the ability to pick one randomly, and a dice with 6 faces and the ability to pick one randomly. That description there is similar enough to warrant thinking about inheritance.

Comment: This kind of approach reduce the risk of rebuilding everything when a new requirement pop out. In approach when you start from creation the base class from coin you are strongly limited. With this solution you can inherit from Die call class as Coin and create no param constructor that will initialize the faces same for Dice. If you do not feel this type of approach to be correct IMHO you are poor designer with few years of experience. Using those three classes we are able to model action like pick random card from the deck. With your approach (probably) this type of new requirement will

Comment: trigger massive structure changes additional architecture with logic that will decide use dice or coin or deck. And this will lead to potential defects in your code. Because when you code everything usually goes right. The problem is when you need to implement some changes. Decomposition and good architecture will allow you to do this easily. Bad one will probably need lot of changes. But if you think that you can create a better design feel free to do it.

Comment: btw thanks for edit on my post.

Comment: I respectfully disagree with what you say above. Your design will not allow you to pick a card from a deck any better than my design. If your such a talented designer with so much experience behind you, why do you fail to see that what I am suggesting is a AbstractFactory design pattern which is widely documented and used in industry. I am sorry your design was really poor, but please do some research before name calling or making assumptions. This will get you started: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern#Definition

Comment: "With your approach (probably) this type of new requirement will trigger massive structure changes additional architecture with logic that will decide use dice or coin or deck" - No it will not, it will require a new class that will have the same methods (pickRandom), but now I can implement additional functionality, like pick 5 randomly or remove a card, which the dice and coin cannot do. The parent class ensures that only the declaration of my card needs to be added. The dice and coin can be left as is, even their definition can be left alone. So much for your years of experience pal.

Comment: Your design is clearly highly unmodifiable and generally poor. Your Face is of string values - how do I assign a numerical value to a card (for BlackJack)? How do I add Die face values (for multiple dice throws)? How can I represent Head/Tail or Win/Lose strings for coins? - your design cannot. Not without "massive structure changes additional architecture with logic" as you so eloquently put it. I can use a Map in my new card class, to assign values to cards. My Dice can have integer values (in an Arraylist) in its class so I can add/subtract total throws. Its an extensible design.

Comment: You have right about that i do not see abstract factory. Could you show me your class structure and design ?. Card do not have numerical values they have Color and Rank. You can inherit from Face and create own type. The face should be an interface that is right but this is only SO example. you just have to create a Card that implement (in this case extend) for Die would be the same. So you can. As Die is only container you can put there anything. ;-).

Comment: About pickRandowm it was only simplified example but i have wrote that for more complex operation you should write your own class for that. So you just create a simple class that do that for you. And you remove the logic from your Die type as it should. Having a logic how to draw a card from deck in deck imply that you should implement  each type of card draw in it. So that hash map is a dead end.

Comment: It is not that my worse but you cold not create any type of logic, and i will not change anything in the base design. I can spend some time to write this type of logic for you. From my point of view every question from your side is quite easy to implement.

Comment: A card has 4 possible Types and 13 possible Ranks. Your Face class does not have that, and implementing that in the Face class will add unnecessary baggage to the Die class. Cards have numerical value in blackjack and several other games (Ace=1, king=11 etc). Now if I am dealing cards and I deal 2 random cards to one player, how do I remove those from the Face[] array? so that the same cards are not dealt to another player? Like I said poor design. If you want to prove me wrong, write your code above and I will show you my code, and lets compare designs?

Comment: This problem exist only when you have logic of game in the structure of Deck. If not then the problem do not exits. As your Face is so complex that string description is not sufficient. Then you should create a new class that inherit from it. Then instead of `Face` you will have `Card`. You can still use the Die to store the deck or you can extend Die and create class Deck. But from definition deck does nothing so IMHO it should be only a object. We can create list of Cards shuffle it and from it initialize deck. Then when we pick next we have always next card.

Comment: So the problem of dealing is that you remove cards from stack. on the end you create new shuffled Deck. Note that deck is only pile of cards it can not shuffle it self. I will wrote you simple black jack .

Comment: Yes and your design also needs to implement flipping coins and rolling dice, and be expandable for anything else that might involve randomisation i.e. roulette wheel? slot machines? etc. Good luck and I will show you my design later.

Comment: Ok. I do not have time for all of that. But the simple black jack http://pastebin.com/4LKxxsAC . What is missing is the logic if card value. But this is minor issue. On the weekend i might some time to implement the rest of it.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll have a look when I get a chance this evening. Really appreciate your efforts.